AMADEUS API token request error Invalid parameters
I am working on this flight tracker project and I am using Amadeus API to get the data, I have registered and got my key but it seems I am having issues to get the authorization token. Could someone please help? I keep getting this error:

{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing', 'code': 38187, 'title': 'Invalid parameters'}

I leave my code here
import os
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from data_manager import DataManager
AMADEUS_END_POINT = "test.api.amadeus.com"

class FlightSearch:
    def __init__(self):
        self._api_key = os.environ["AMADEUS_API_KEY"]
        self._api_secret = os.environ["AMADEUS_API_SECRET"]
        self._header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-form-urlencoded"
}
        self.token = {}


    def get_destination_code(self, city_name):
        # Return "TESTING" for now to make sure Sheety is working. Get AMADEUS API data later.
        #request = requests.get(url=AMADEUS_END_POINT)
        code = "Te"
        return code

    def get_new_token(self):
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self._api_key, self._api_secret)
        body = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }
        response = requests.post(url="https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token", headers=self._header, data=body, auth=auth)
        data = response.json()
        print(data)

    #This class is responsible for talking to the Flight Search API.

I have tried the to use key and secret directly but I keep getting the same error. as well I have tried different formats for the body instead of using HTTPBasicAuth() it all gives the same error.
Any recommendations? what do I do?

Why are you using HTTP Basic auth? The documentation doesn't mention that and clearly shows how to send the client id and secret.

I have tried both with out it to. Here is my code with out it
def get_new_token(self):
    header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-form-urlencoded"
    }
    body = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": self._api_key,
        "client_secret": self._api_secret
    }
    response = requests.post(url="https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token", headers=header, data=body)
    self.token = response.json()
    print(f"Your token is {self.token}")
    return self.token


I found a solution around this. It struggled getting the api_key and api_secret as a enivronmental variable. All you have to do is to put it as variables in your class attributes.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This doesn’t really answer the original question.
